# MongoDB db files movement

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodump

I am using mongodb and I have changed the dbpath. Can I just copy all the files from the earlier dbpath to the new dbpath?

PS: I have come across the mongodump alternative which might be a bit tedious. So I am interested in knwoing whether plain copying work?

Comment: Another issue is we get a read error while copying those db files which I am guessing is because of mongo creating a null file of a particular size and it's more like reading before writing which create an I/O error. Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just do a normal copy if you shutdown your mongod first. You don't need to copy mongod.lock.

Comment: But we get a read error while copying those db files which I am guessing is because of mongo creating a null file of a particular size and it's more like reading before writing which create an I/O error. Any comments?

Comment: Did you shutdown mongod like I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I did shut it down. I am getting this however --> cp: reading `options.1': Input/output error